Enumeration results using lspci
I am relatively new to PCIe so please excuse me for my ignorance. The question involves enumeration. I would think if you did a lspci -vvv that you would get enough information to completely piece together what the PCIe network looks like. I understand the concepts of primary, secondary and subordinate bus numbers. The primary is the one that faces upstream. The secondary is the one that faces downstream, and the subordinate is the maximum downstream bus - at least I hope I got those right.
Here is an example of a small piece of the lspci output:
7:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Physical Slot: 0
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 27
NUMA node: 0
Bus: primary=17, secondary=18, subordinate=18, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
Memory behind bridge: a1b00000-a1bfffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a1900000-00000000a1afffff
Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
BridgeCtl: Parity+ SERR+ NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

It shows a primary bus value of 17 for this particular bridge. I would expect that somewhere in the lspci output there would be another listing with secondary bus of 17 so that I could understand where it attaches. Am I looking at this wrong?
I had also run lspci -tv but I found the same thing. There wasn't really any additional connectivity information but instead looked like a "pruned" tree.
Could it be that the answer is in Capabilities which I don't have access to?


It shows a primary bus value of 17 for this particular bridge. I would expect that somewhere in the lspci output there would be another listing with secondary bus of 17 so that I could understand where it attaches. Am I looking at this wrong?

First, I'm pretty sure that's backwards – primary bus is the bridge's own bus number, while secondary corresponds to the lowest bus number of a downstream device (and subordinate is the highest bus number).
That is, 'primary=17 secondary=18' means that the bridge itself is 17:00.0 and something downstream would be 18:xx.x – but you wouldn't necessarily see 'primary=18' because this entire line only shows up for bridges.
Second, the secondary–subordinate bus numbers are reserved for this bridge even if it doesn't necessarily have a downstream device connected at the moment. The lspci -tv shows an empty slot in such cases.
(In general, what lspci -tv shows you probably is what the network looks like, with bridges implicit in the display.)
Use lspci -PP to visualize the nesting of bridged devices in a different format – if this particular bridge has a downstream, it should be listed as 17:00.0/18.00.0. If not (e.g. the bridge has just an empty port), then instead find some other downstream device that is present, then trace back to its parent bridge and the bus numbers should correspond.

An example from one bridge-heavy server (old enough that it includes some Conventional PCI, from which PCI-Express inherited the logical topology):
# lspci -vvv | egrep "PCI bridge:|secondary"
[...]
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x4 Port 2 (rev 12) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=09, sec-latency=0
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x4 Port 3 (rev 12) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x8 Port 4-5 (rev 12) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=0a, subordinate=0a, sec-latency=0
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x4 Port 5 (rev 12) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=0b, subordinate=0b, sec-latency=0
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x8 Port 6-7 (rev 12) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=0c, subordinate=0c, sec-latency=0
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x4 Port 7 (rev 12) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=0d, subordinate=0d, sec-latency=0
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d9) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=0e, subordinate=0e, sec-latency=32
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom EPB PCI-Express to PCI-X Bridge (rev c3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=02, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=64
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6311ESB/6321ESB PCI Express Upstream Port (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=04, secondary=05, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
04:00.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6311ESB/6321ESB PCI Express to PCI-X Bridge (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=04, secondary=09, subordinate=09, sec-latency=64
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6311ESB/6321ESB PCI Express Downstream Port E1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=05, secondary=06, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6311ESB/6321ESB PCI Express Downstream Port E2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=05, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom EPB PCI-Express to PCI-X Bridge (rev c3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=64

# lspci -PP
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5000X Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 12)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x4 Port 2 (rev 12)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x4 Port 3 (rev 12)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x8 Port 4-5 (rev 12)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x4 Port 5 (rev 12)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x8 Port 6-7 (rev 12)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset PCI Express x4 Port 7 (rev 12)
00:10.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset FSB Registers (rev 12)
00:10.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset FSB Registers (rev 12)
00:10.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset FSB Registers (rev 12)
00:11.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset Reserved Registers (rev 12)
00:13.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset Reserved Registers (rev 12)
00:15.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset FBD Registers (rev 12)
00:16.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset FBD Registers (rev 12)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 09)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #1 (rev 09)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #2 (rev 09)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #3 (rev 09)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset EHCI USB2 Controller (rev 09)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d9)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 09)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB IDE Controller (rev 09)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset SATA IDE Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0/01:00.0 RAID bus controller: Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS 1078 (rev 04)
00:1c.0/02:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom EPB PCI-Express to PCI-X Bridge (rev c3)
00:1c.0/02:00.0/03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM5708 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 12)
00:02.0/04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6311ESB/6321ESB PCI Express Upstream Port (rev 01)
00:02.0/04:00.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6311ESB/6321ESB PCI Express to PCI-X Bridge (rev 01)
00:02.0/04:00.0/05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6311ESB/6321ESB PCI Express Downstream Port E1 (rev 01)
00:02.0/04:00.0/05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6311ESB/6321ESB PCI Express Downstream Port E2 (rev 01)
00:02.0/04:00.0/05:00.0/06:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom EPB PCI-Express to PCI-X Bridge (rev c3)
00:02.0/04:00.0/05:00.0/06:00.0/07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM5708 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 12)
00:02.0/04:00.0/05:01.0/08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB/82571GB Gigabit Ethernet Controller D0/D1 (copper applications) (rev 06)
00:02.0/04:00.0/05:01.0/08:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB/82571GB Gigabit Ethernet Controller D0/D1 (copper applications) (rev 06)
00:1e.0/0e:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] ES1000 (rev 02)

# lspci -tv
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation 5000X Chipset Memory Controller Hub
           +-02.0-[04-09]--+-00.0-[05-08]--+-00.0-[06-07]----00.0-[07]----00.0  Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM5708 Gigabit Ethernet
           |               |               \-01.0-[08]--+-00.0  Intel Corporation 82571EB/82571GB Gigabit Ethernet Controller D0/D1 (copper applications)
           |               |                            \-00.1  Intel Corporation 82571EB/82571GB Gigabit Ethernet Controller D0/D1 (copper applications)
           |               \-00.3-[09]--
           +-03.0-[01]----00.0  Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS 1078
           +-04.0-[0a]--
           +-05.0-[0b]--
           +-06.0-[0c]--
           +-07.0-[0d]--
           +-10.0  Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset FSB Registers
           +-10.1  Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset FSB Registers
           +-10.2  Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset FSB Registers
           +-11.0  Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset Reserved Registers
           +-13.0  Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset Reserved Registers
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset FBD Registers
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation 5000 Series Chipset FBD Registers
           +-1c.0-[02-03]----00.0-[03]----00.0  Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM5708 Gigabit Ethernet
           +-1d.0  Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #1
           +-1d.1  Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #2
           +-1d.2  Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #3
           +-1d.7  Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset EHCI USB2 Controller
           +-1e.0-[0e]----0d.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] ES1000
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset LPC Interface Controller
           +-1f.1  Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB IDE Controller
           \-1f.2  Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset SATA IDE Controller


Thank you grawity_u1686! I must have a different (older?) version of lspci. I cannot use the -PP switch. It doesn't output anything and just returns to the Linux prompt.

They added -P in pciutils version 3.6.2 (2018). If yours is older, study the Dell server output above, e.g. the +-02.0-[04-09] showing a bridge 00:02.0 (on primary bus 00) branching off to secondary bus 04:xx with subordinate buses going up to 09:xx – the item \-00.3 to its right is therefore 04:00.3 (which has primary=04, secondary=09) and the empty space to the right of [09]- would be 09:00.0 if it weren't empty. That is, nothing is pruned, just squeezed into unreadable format.

Thanks again grawity_u1686 !!
